# Why can I convert FAT32 -> NTFS, but not the other way around?

Tags: ntfs, fat32

I see some programs claim `FAT32 -> NTFS` conversion, although I just tried with a 100% filled up FAT32 SD card which formatted the drive completely.

How are programs able to do `FAT32 -> NTFS` but not `NTFS -> FAT32`?

Comment: downgrading in that fashion would be much trickier and much less certian to work, so I'd guess most people don't want to write a process to do the conversion, and its almost certian that some data would be lost (as NTFS stores lots of types of metadata that is not replicatable on FAT32). but we can only speculate on why no one has bothered.

Comment: You can basically format your SD Card with everything you want. The Data will be "lost" afterwards. But the question ist, whether your formating software supports this. In doubt, I recomend a live-Linux with gparted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem with an NTFS to FAT32 conversion is that NTFS is a far more complex file system with many features that are unsupported by FAT32. Just some of these features:

- File and folder Security
- File sizes over 4GB
- File Compression
- File encryption
- Alternate data streams
- Hard and soft links
- Sparse files
- Volume shadow copy

Some of these features could cause data loss and there may be serious implications for applications or the user. Files larger than 4GB would be lost. Compression and encryption would have to be removed before conversion because it would be impossible after. Encryption could only be removed by the account that encrypted them. If this was not done the files would be lost.

It would be very difficult to determine before conversion how serious these issues might be. The user probably wouldn't know. If they did cause a problem in most cases the only solution would be a restore from an image backup, which most people would not have. And some of the problems may not be discovered until long after the conversion

That is why Microsoft does not supply a utility that can convert NTFS to FAT32. If the conversion really is necessary there are third party tools that can do this. But the user must assume responsibility for any problems it may cause.

Comment: That's really interesting. So many things I didn't know :) Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

If you google "convert NTFS to FAT32" you get for example: `http://www.aomeitech.com/n2f/convert-ntfs-to-fat32.html`. So it's possible to convert this way.

Comment: But that's what I'm asking.

Comment: @MortenMoulder But... I thought you were under the impression that it was impossible.

Comment: Definitely not. I was under the impression that it works, but I couldn't get it to work with mine (perhaps because the SD card was 100% full and as far as I have read, some programs (like AOMEI) require a 3% free space.